# Xcode program: Text box that the user can interact with through touch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textbox

I am new to Xcode and Swift.

I want to create a text box for a video game that acts as the dialogue between the game and the user. for example I want the text box to say (character name) walked 10 paces or "Used 'detect evil' orc within 60'. "

I also want the ability for the user to pressure touch this chat text message which is sent from the computer and then do a series of actions. For example if a paladin detects evil maybe the next course of action would be to hide or prepare to fight. Any ideas on how to set this up? I have been trying to create this on Main.storyboard. Can I only achieve this through the ViewController or one of the delegates?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can only achieve this by coding (by using Storyboards as your ally of course!)

If you want to have a text box that is "clickable", what first comes to mind is just a button, that have no background color, so it looks just like text.

Then you need to create a method inside of your ViewController, ideally something like:

```swift
@IBAction func dialogBoxTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
// your code goes here
}
```

And connect your button to this function by setting up a `touchUpInside` method in the Storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. Do you think that a table view controller with computer outputs as the objects in the table would achieve this desired textbox too? I want to allow the user to scroll through the text (as well as interact with it ) to look for clues etc. that they might need later. Can I achieve this with the button and aforementioned method in a table view viewcontroller ?